# Why does the composition of functions $g(f(x))$ require the codomain of $f$, and not its image, be the same as the domain of $g$?

Tags: functions, definition, function-and-relation-composition

As the question title states, for a composition of functions $f(g(x))$ I was taught that the domain of $g$ has to be the same as the codomain of $f$. Why? Can't you say that the image of $f$ and the domain of g must be the same? Perhaps when I was taught it was simply poorly worded and should have been that the domain of $g$ must be a subset of the codomain of $f$? Surely only every point produced by the map $f$, ie $f$'s image, needs to be then mapped by $g$.

Comment: $gof(x)=g(f(x))$ thus we have to have $f(X)\subseteq$ domain$g$

Comment: It is necessary that  the image of $f$ is contained in the domain of $g$, and sufficient that the codomain of $f$ is equal to the domain of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a composition of function written as $f(g(x))$ this is equivalent to

$x \rightarrow g(x) \rightarrow f(g(x))$

applying $g$ and then $f$ on the image of $g$. This operation makes sense only when the image of $g$ is contained in the domain of $f$

Answer (score 0):

$g\circ f(x)$ will be good defined if $x \in Dom(f) \land f(x) \in Dom(g)$, so in the last part: $f(x) \in Dom(g)$ you can note that the images of $f$ i.e, $f(x)$ are a subset of $Dom(g)$ and therefore $Dom(g)$ can be a codomain of $f(x)$. Remember that any subset that contains the images of a function can be a codomain.

So, in resume. Let $A = Dom(f), B= Dom(g)$ And you know that $Im(f) \subseteq B$ to $gof$ be defined, and since $Im(f) \subseteq B$, $B$ contains the images hence is a codomain.

Now, you can define the functions as: $f: A\to B, g: B \to C$